# What would be a reason to use the Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) to combine data?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, similarities, rms

In this [machine learning tutorial](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/similarity/manual-similarity) by Google they use the Root Mean Square to create a similarity measure between two shoes.

They first calculate the difference between the size of two shoes and then do the same for their price. Finally with those two values they compute Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) however they don't explain why it's appropriate to do so.

Could someone explain why would you use RMSE or in what case does it apply?

Comment: RMSE is euclidean distance.  For distance in shoe sizes, it is literally the most physically appropriate measure of difference.  I personally think absolute difference is better for cash value.  Better to ask the author for their justification.

Comment: RMSE is the mean of the euclidean distance then?

Comment: @EngrStudent would you mind also explain why in your opinion the absolute difference is better for cash value?

Comment: They first normalize then apply RMSE. In any case the tutorial is one HOW to create similarity measure, and NOT WHY it has to be RMSE. They are not combining data. That’s notwhatsimilarity for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, this tutorial is mostly interested in presenting how to do clustering with a manually created similarity measure, and use RMSE as a natural choice for coming up with a similarity measure. So, it's not because the Euclidean distance (a scaled version of it to be precise) is the best choice for shoe + price feature pair. They also finish with saying

> In general, your similarity measure must directly correspond to the actual similarity.

Noting that the choice of similarity which suits best to your data and problem's needs is left to you.

Comment: Could you expand on why RMSE is a natural choice for coming up with a similarity measure? This will help me decide what to do on my own data.

Comment: Because both features are numeric and the Euclidean distance between two points is the most natural one that comes to one's mind. Not saying it should be the choice. Most libraries measure Euclidean distance by default in their dist functions.

Answer (score 1):

RMSE is a widely applicable and often used error function, but it is certainly not the only one or the best one for all circumstances. It has the sometimes-desired feature that bigger differences count for more, so a difference of two shoe sizes will more than double the feature-wise error compared to a difference of just one shoe size. Under this measure, two shoes that have a standardized size difference of 0.1 and a standardized price difference of 0.1 are more similar than two shoes of identical size but with a standardized price difference of 0.2.  You can contrast this with the mean absolute error (MAE), for example, which simply sums up the magnitude of differences - here, all differences count for the same weight, larger differences do not count for exponentially more error. With MAE, the previously mentioned pairs of shoes (0.1 and 0.1 difference vs. 0 and 0.2 difference) are identically "different" from one another.

The choice of error function will be domain dependent. The RMSE is a reasonable choice for many applications, and seems to be chosen in this example for convenience. Other error measures would also be justifiable for this problem, and there's nothing particularly special about this case to suggest that RMSE is inherently the best error measure to use here.

Comment: If I understand correctly RMSE has more granularity when it comes to similarity then MAE.

Comment: @WindBreeze Not sure what you mean by "granularity" for that to be true. RMSE simply puts more weight on larger errors, but it doesn't draw any more fine-grained distinctions in the difference measure for arbitrary samples. 100 pairs of samples may yield 100 different similarity measures by either RMSE or MAE, but there's no reason to expect that RMSE will allow you more "resolution" to determine the most similar pairs - it's just a different measure.

Comment: @WindBreeze The misunderstanding may have come from my particular example of RMSE vs. MAE, but it's not the case that one will always have differences where the other does not. My example showed two pairs of samples that had identical MAE but different RMSE, but you could also have two pairs with identical RMSE but different MAE (e.g. a pair with a price difference of 1.41 and a size difference of 1.41 has the same RMSE as a pair with a price difference of 0 and a size difference of 2, but different MAE). Either measure may find differences where the other does not.